# Protractor expect an element to not be present and receive an error saying it cannot be found

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I've searched numerous forums for users with a similar issue to no avail. My issue is as follows:

I'm writing a Protractor test which expects a HTML element to not be present:

```
expect(result[0].$('#edit').isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

When I run this test, it throws the following error:

`No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("#edit")`

Am I wrong to find it hard to wrap my head around this? I imagine this would pass the test since I expect the element to not be available. If it was somehow available, it would just say: `Expected true to be false` or something similar.

Any clarification will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it with [`isElementPresent()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isElementPresent) calling it on `result[0]`:

```
expect(result[0].isElementPresent(by.css('#edit'))).toBe(false);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in the same error being thrown.

Comment: @TomNijs interesting, I have a similar case, except that I'm using `browser.isElementPresent()`, but it works for me..could you provide a complete traceback and your protractor configuration. Also, which version are you using? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you can find the full stacktrace here: [pastebinlink](http://pastebin.com/Rp33phgd)

Comment: @TomNijs thanks, could you please switch back to jasmine 1 and run the test?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar on how to downgrade to Jasmine1, is this something worth checking into and is it reversible?

Comment: @TomNijs i think it is just switching to `jasmine` from `jasmine2` in your config, look for `framework` key.

Comment: I've changed it to Jasmine and ran the tests again, the new stacktrace is quite extensive: http://pastebin.com/kPAkFXcd

Comment: @TomNijs quick sanity check. Are you sure it is failing on this particular line? Thanks.

Comment: I am, It's been bothering me for several hours. Thanks for checking

Comment: This was firing against a server with 300ms+ latency which apparently caused some issues with the tests. I tried firing against a server here in Europe which resolved the issue. To me it seems unrelated but it's not occuring anymore.